# Slices in $B_X$ and $B_{X^*}$

Tags: functional-analysis, geometry, banach-spaces

As far, we have these definitions:

$S(X, x^∗, \delta) = \{x \in B_X : x^∗(x) \geq 1 − \delta\}$

$S(X^∗, x, \delta) = \{x^∗ \in B_{X^∗} : x^∗(x) \geq 1 − \delta\}$,

which are the slices of $B_X$ and $B_{X^*}$ determined by
$x^∗$, $\delta$ and $x$, $\delta$ respectively.

But I have not understood the term clearly. Also, I want to visualise its elements as well. Can anyone please suggest to me any book or material?

Answer (score 1):

Visualize....

Say our Banach space $X$ is two-dimensional.  Say our unit ball $B_X$ is
[image: A1]

Let $x^*$ be a linear functional. Then a level-set $\{x : x^*(x) = \alpha\}$ is a line (in general, a hyperplane).

[image: A2]

As $\alpha$ varies, we get a family of parallel lines.

If $x^*$ is a functional of norm one, then the hyperplane
$\{x:x^*(x) = 1\}$ is a supporting hyperplane of the ball $B_X$:

[image: A3]

(To see this, use the definition of norm of a linear functional.)

Finally, if $\delta>0$ is small, the
hyperplane $\{x: x^*(x)=1-\delta\}$ is goes only slightly
inside the ball.

[image: A4]

And the **slice** $S(X, x^*,\delta)$ is the colored region here:
[image: A5]

Don't you think that "slice" is an appropriate name for this?

Comment: Thank you so much